# How to load a Javascript file without Script tag?

Tags: javascript

I have a code where I have nested <script> tag, the inner script tag does nothing but loads another Javascript file using src attribute. Because, How in my code, the inner script tag is closing the outer script.

Since I am already inside JavaScript mode, is there a way to load another script without using <script src=""> call?

Comment: You can use jQuery's [$.getScript method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/). There are other methods as well. You can refer **require.js**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = "path_to_the_file.js";

document.body.appendChild(js);
```

but this is asynchronous, so you have to wait until the script is loaded to use it -

```
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = "path_to_the_file.js";

js.onload = function() {
 //Code using this script here
};

document.body.appendChild(js);
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Fletch, my ES2015 equivalent:

```
document.body.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement('script'), {
  type: 'text/javascript',
  src: 'http://external.script.url',
  onload: () => this.onScriptLoaded()
}));
```