# Load external script without <script> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I faced with a problem and right now I don't know how to solve.
I'm using some platform where I can create a shop and sell some goods. This platform allows users customize shop style and some code into header and footer. The big minus of that platform is there is no search. Well, I try to add google search into the website. Google give javascript code to add website. But problem is that platform not allow you add `<script>` tag into header. 
Is there any way to add code into header without `<script>` tag?

Comment: Can you add the `<script>` tag elsewhere in the code? It will still run even if it's not in the `<head>`.

Comment: It allow me add code to only header and footer.

Comment: You probably can't add any scripts since it would be a huge security hole.

Comment: if you can modify existing script file then you can import your new script into..but as you said you wish to add google script into you have to again customize it.

Comment: Hope this link will solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053005/how-to-load-a-javascript-file-without-script-tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load a Javascript file without Script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053005/how-to-load-a-javascript-file-without-script-tag)

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = document.createElement("script");
x.type = "text/javascript";
x.src = "jsfile.js";
document.body.appendChild(x);
```